C# API JWT token authentication
First off - apologies very new to building APIs, I have configured my API with database context and have created a Login API that issue a JWT Token. The token issues correctly and if in Swagger I authorise with the token I can return data successfully.
Now the interesting part is that when I don't use a JWT token, even though the controller is marked as [Authorise] it returns a 401 (expected since no token) but still returns the ok 200 after and my data set.
So the question is - is this a quirk in Swagger or am I doing something very wrong here?
Really appreciate some help
Code of controller
namespace CBF_API.controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CbfContext _context;
        public ClientsController(CbfContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        //get api/clients
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Client>>> GetAllClients()
        {
            List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
            clients = await _context.Clients.ToListAsync();

            return Ok(clients);
        }
    }
}


Code of Program.cs for authentication

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(cfg => {
    cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x => {
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = false;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.UTF8
            .GetBytes(builder.Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"])
        ),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});


it returns a 401 (expected since no token) but still returns the ok 200 it return 401 or 200 then? Not quite clear from the description.

you probably have misconfiguration, show your Configure and ConfigureServices codes

Yea its bizzare - it returns both 401 and 200 but only in swagger, i tried it in browser and postman and all correct returns 401 only - does this mean this is a swagger "feature"? :D

200 in Swagger but: 200 when you call it through swagger or 200 when swagger shows the metadata?

401 error code for server response, then under responses 200 success and i get metadata. So i suppose its just not me understanding swagger and all is as it should. thanks guys.

Hows your full program.cs file? Have you added app.UseAuthentication();  app.UseAuthorization(); middleware references within your program.cs file?

Swagger returns 401 and a "Sample" 200 with metadata of the call rather than throwing a full error like postman or web would do. thanks again folks

You can close your question as it won't possibly bring other answers at the moment.
